# Choose Directory to create directory in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, dialog, pyqt5

I am creating a Save As... function on PyQt5.

The function is supposed to open a file dialog, and let the user specify the directory they want.

Take for example certain applications like Steam. When you save steam, they let you choose a directory to save it in.

User input: D://
But then they will create D://Steam/ for the user. This D://Steam/ folder's name is default and can be changed to anything the user wants For eg: D://asdfgh/ and all content will be downloaded there.

You could think of the function the same as Save As... function in Microsoft Word, but instead of a word document, it is a directory.

This is my current code

```
saveLocation = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Save As...", os.getenv('HOME'))
    if saveLocation:
        currentSaveLocation = saveLocation
        fromDirectory = Main.tempPath
        toDirectory = saveLocation
        copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory)
```

I am unable to save the files into a named directory.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. With `getExistingDirectory` you get an *existing* path, do you want the user to be able to choose a "target" directory, no matter if it exists or not?

Comment: @musicamante yes, I want the user to able to choose a target directory no matter if it exists or not. The depth of the directory should only be +1 of current directory though, for example C://newdir is acceptable but C://new/dir is unacceptable (assuming new does not exist in C drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a possibly not yet existing path, using the static methods of QFileDialog is not a viable solution. Also, we cannot use the native OS file dialogs, as, like the static methods, they don't give enough control.

We need to do some little "hacking", considering the following aspects:

- if the dialog is set in `Directory` fileMode, writing a non existing path disables the Open button;
- even if the button is disabled, when pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> in the line edit with a non existing path, the dialog will still complain about the non existing path;

So, these precautions must be taken:

- use the non native file dialog, so that we can have access to the child widgets;
- get the "Open" button so that we can manually enable it when required;
- get the line edit of the dialog and *manually* enable the button whenever the path text is changed and we detect a valid path;
- *overwrite* the `accept()` method of the dialog in order to ignore the warning, and use the base `QDialog.accept()` method;

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.pathEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText='Select path...')
        self.button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='...')
        layout.addWidget(self.pathEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.selectTarget)

    def selectTarget(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)

        if self.pathEdit.text():
            dialog.setDirectory(self.pathEdit.text())

        dialog.setFileMode(dialog.Directory)

        # we cannot use the native dialog, because we need control over the UI
        options = dialog.Options(dialog.DontUseNativeDialog | dialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        dialog.setOptions(options)

        def checkLineEdit(path):
            if not path:
                return
            if path.endswith(QtCore.QDir.separator()):
                return checkLineEdit(path.rstrip(QtCore.QDir.separator()))
            path = QtCore.QFileInfo(path)
            if path.exists() or QtCore.QFileInfo(path.absolutePath()).exists():
                button.setEnabled(True)
                return True

        # get the "Open" button in the dialog
        button = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox).button(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Open)

        # get the line edit used for the path
        lineEdit = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
        lineEdit.textChanged.connect(checkLineEdit)

        # override the existing accept() method, otherwise selectedFiles() will 
        # complain about selecting a non existing path
        def accept():
            if checkLineEdit(lineEdit.text()):
                # if the path is acceptable, call the base accept() implementation
                QtWidgets.QDialog.accept(dialog)
        dialog.accept = accept

        if dialog.exec_() and dialog.selectedFiles():
            path = QtCore.QFileInfo(dialog.selectedFiles()[0]).absoluteFilePath()
            self.pathEdit.setText(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is a good attempt... but unfortunately substituting the `accept` method like this has a fatal flaw, at least on my machine (W10): if, when you enter a few alphanum characters which causes a drop-down to occur in the "Directory" box in the dialog (because one or more subdirectories' names start with these characters), and then "Choose", unfortunately the drop-down is left visible even after the dialog has gone. A workaround is to create the directory using the "create folder" icon in the dialog, and then select this after it has been created, using "Choose".

Comment: @mikerodent monkey patching *could* create some issues in certain cases (so, subclassing QFileDialog should be more appropriate). The drop-down might be an unrelated platform bug (are you sure you're *not* using the native dialog, btw?), but it shouldn't happen since that's exactly what QFileDialog::accept() actually does. A *correct* workaround would be to check the completer popup on the `fileNameEdit` (and also do more debugging with a subclass).

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit puzzled because 1) I'm using `DontUseNativeDialog` and 2) even the most basic substitution of the `accept` method causes this "ghost" drop-down to remain. Incidentally, I'd prefer a `pathlib` or `os` approach to finding whether the directory exists: it seems that even entering keystrokes triggers a `True` response to the test involving `QFileInfo`.