# Identify signal emitted when return key is pressed in a QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qfiledialog

I'm implementing some customised behaviour for a QFileDialog.

```
reference_dir = r'D:\My Documents\month' 
create_dir_dialog.setDirectory(reference_dir)
create_dir_dialog.setFileMode(create_dir_dialog.Directory)
options = create_dir_dialog.Options(create_dir_dialog.DontUseNativeDialog | create_dir_dialog.ShowDirsOnly)
create_dir_dialog.setOptions(options)
# identify "Choose" button
choose_button = create_dir_dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox).button(
    QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Open)
# disconnect "clicked" signal from this button
choose_button.disconnect()
def check_line_edit(path):
    # this slot handles enablement of the "Choose" button: if the text 
    # corresponds to an already-existing directory the button is disabled.
    # This is because we are trying to create a new directory.
    ...

# get the line edit used for the path
lineEdit = create_dir_dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
lineEdit.textChanged.connect(check_line_edit)
def create_dir_and_proj():
    # this function creates a directory based on the text in the QLE
    new_dir = lineEdit.text()
    ...
    create_dir_dialog.close() # programmatically close the dialog
# use the above method as the slot for the clicked signal    
choose_button.clicked.connect(create_dir_and_proj)

dlg_result = create_dir_dialog.exec_()
# thread gets held up here
```

To my delight this works OK.

There's only one fly in the ointment: if, instead of clicking "Choose" with the mouse or using the mnemonic Alt-C to cause the click (both of which cause `create_dir_and_proj` to run OK), I just press "Return" key when focus is on the dialog, the previous (standard) behaviour occurs, i.e. the behaviour (slot) that I disconnected from the "Choose" button's `click` signal. This then causes a message box to come up saying "directory does not exist". But the point is that my new slot wants to create the new directory as entered by the user.

I surmise that this is because the "Choose" button is the "default" button of the dialog, and that things have been wired up so that this "Return-key-pressed" signal is wired up to the standard slot as normally used by the "Choose" button.

How do I get hold of this signal with a view to disconnecting it and wiring up a new slot (i.e. the above `create_dir_and_proj` function)?

Comment: That's no "signal", it's QDialog that automatically accepts when Enter is pressed (just like it rejects when pressing Esc) and that's why I had to overwrite `accept` [in the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357388). If it still doesn't work, subclass and implement `event`, or install an event filter and/or properly override accept in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't currently implemented a subclass of QFileDialog here, and all attempts to just "swap in" a new `event` (or `keyPressEvent`) method on the instance have failed. I also get the annoying phenomenon as described in my comments to that answer, unfortunately.  It may be an intermittent phenomenon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message-box will appear when the line-edit has focus and you press return/enter. The `returnPressed` signal of the line-edit is connected to the `QFileDialog.accept` slot. The resulting behaviour will then depend on the `FileMode`. For the `Directory` mode, this equates to a request to open the specified directory, which will obviously fail if it doesn't exist.

To override this behviour, you can simply connect your own slot:

```
lineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect()
lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(create_dir_and_proj)
```

When the line-edit does not have the focus, pressing return/enter will activate the default button (unless the current focus-widget has built-in behaviour of its own: e.g. navigating to the selected directory in the tree-view). Since you've connected your own slot to the `clicked` signal of this button, your slot will be called by default.

**UPDATE**:

It seems that connecting to a Python slot that forms a closure over the dialog can affect the order in which objects get deleted. This may sometimes result in the line-edit completer popup being left without a parent after the dialog closes, which means it won't get deleted and may remain visible on screen. A couple of possible work-arounds are to either explicitly close the popup inside the slot:

```
def create_dir_and_proj():
    lineEdit.completer().popup().hide()
    dialog.close()
```

or disconnect all signals connected to the slot before closing:

```
def create_dir_and_proj():
    choose_button.clicked.disconnect()
    lineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect()
    dialog.close()
```

(NB: I have only tested this on Linux; there's no guarantee the behaviour will be the same on other platforms).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As with the related answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357388/595305) by Musicamente, however, the comment I made there applies, at least in a W10 OS (or my system anyway): pressing Return does do what is intended, but it leaves behind a little snippet of the "picture" of a bit of the dialog. No doubt due to `paint` or `repaint` (or however PyQt5 does this) not quite being able to do its job. I.e. another fly in the ointment rears its ugly head. Sigh.

Comment: @mikerodent in those comments you pointed out that what remained was the popup, have you checked the lineedit's completer popup as suggested?

Comment: I haven't got around that that, at least in part because I didn't and don't yet understand what the "completer popup" actually is. Yes, I need to do some research. And maybe subclass as suggested. Incidentally, latest experiments seem to suggest that in this case this "lingering image" phenomenon is quite intermittent...

Comment: @mikerodent You should be able to deal with the lingering completer popup by calling `lineEdit.completer().popup().hide()` before closing the dialog.

Comment: @mikerodent that depends on the Qt platform plugin that might not correctly manage events. The completer popup is the drop down that suggests the path based on the typed letter. A QLineEdit can have a QCompleter set that uses a model to provide appropriate suggestions based on the typed text; the file name edit field has a QCompleter subclass that uses QFileSystemModel and some custom functions that provide suggestions based on the current directory or absolute paths typed there. You can find the line edit using `dialog.findChild('fileNameEdit', QLineEdit)`, then do what ekhumoro suggests.

Comment: @musicamante Testing on linux, if I connect `returnPressed` directly to the `accept` or `close` slot, and also *don't* connect anything to the button, the completer popup is automatically closed. It seems very hard to explain that as anything other than a bug. (I also see the same behaviour in pyside). I'd be interested to know if anyone else can reproduce it.

Comment: @musicamante After some more experimentation, the weirdness goes even deeper. It seems that when the button is connected to a python slot that references the dialog, it somehow stops the popup closing - *even though the slot is never called*. I suppose the closure must somehow change the order in which the objects are deleted, which leaves the popup without a parent. Disconnecting any signals connected to the slot before closing the dialog makes the problem go away.

Comment: @mikerodent See my updated answer for some possible work-arounds for the other issues.